# Java Unzip quits after processing xlsx file

Tags: java, xlsx, unzip

I'm unzipping a directory that contains a variety of files.  Once the unzip utility reaches the first Excel (xlsx) file, it unzips the excel file and then exits without processing the remaining files.  What am I doing wrong?

The unzip code is:

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

try{

    //create output directory is not exists
    File folder = new File(outputFolder);
    if(!folder.exists()){
        folder.mkdir();
    }

    //get the zip file content
    ZipInputStream zis = zipFile;
    //get the zipped file list entry
    ZipEntry ze = zis.getNextEntry();

    while(ze!=null && !ze.getName().contains("__MACOSX")){

        if (ze.isDirectory()) {
            String folderPath = outputFolder + "/" + ze.getName();
            File subFolder = new File(folderPath);
            subFolder.mkdir();
        }
        else {

            String fileName = ze.getName();
            File newFile = new File(outputFolder + File.separator + fileName);

            System.out.println("file unzipped : " + newFile.getAbsoluteFile());

            //create folders
             new File(newFile.getParent()).mkdirs();

            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(newFile);

            int len;
            while ((len = zis.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                fos.write(buffer, 0, len);
            }

            fos.close();
        }
        ze = zis.getNextEntry();
    }

    zis.closeEntry();
    zis.close();

    System.out.println("Done");

}catch(IOException ex){
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: provide a sample directory listing and a printout of what your program outputs exactly.

Comment: Your code works on my side, with a zip file containing several files and a `xlsx` file. Do you have an exception thrown ? What's inside your zip file exactly ? Could you share it ?

Comment: No exception is thrown, it processes all of the files through the xlsx file, prints "Done" and exits.   The zip file contains nibs, images, xml, and xlsx.  Unfortunately, I can't share the directory or files.  It helps a lot to know that the code works elsewhere...perhaps it is something in the excel file itself.  If I remove that file from the directory, the unzip utility works (all files are unzipped).